# Electrics tag needed?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is the [electrics](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrics) tag needed?  If so, what is it's purpose?

Answer (score 5):

Hmmm - we have three similar tags - [electrics](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrics), [electrical](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrical) and [electronics](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electronics)

To my mind, electrics and electrical both describe tha main electrical system of the car - fuses, wiring etc, and one should probably be a synonym of the other.

Electronics to me describes things with chips in, such as computers, ecus etc, so is distinct.

Comment: Agree with this, Electrics and electrical could perhaps be merged.

Answer (score 1):

They seem very distinct to me.  They are certainly related, but all point to possibly different resolutions and skill sets.

```
Electrical - Wiring
Electronics - Computers and sensors
Electrics - Vehicles powered by electric motors
```

Comment: "Vehicles powered by electric motors" is coverd by [tag:electric vehicle]

Comment: Yeah, "electrics" should be got rid of.